# Javascript array as parameter for JQuery $.post call to aspx file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, post

It seems that this question was asked several times, but never with the combination of components that I'm using, therefore a new question:
My current problem is that I cannot seem to provide a javascript array to the POST call, it always splits every entry in the array up and makes non.unique POST parameters out of them. This is what I currently have:

```
var arr = new Array(); // filled with strings
var brr = new Array(); // also filled with strings
var id = 1;
```

// filling the arrays here, everything looks fine in JS debugging, array properly filled

```
param2 = {
            "type": "getXY",
            "firstArray": arr,
            "secondArray": brr,
            "someID": id
        }

$.post("process.aspx", param2, function (result) {
        // If successfull, do stuff
    }, "json");
```

This is the result that gets sent to the aspx( Form Data in Chrome dev tools):

```
type:getXY
arr[]:225
arr[]:226
secondArray[]:Hardware
secondArray[]:Hardware
someID:1
```

On the other side (the aspx):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearContent();

            if (Request.Form["type"] != null)
            {
                // Determine what kind of data shall be retrieved
                switch(Request.Form["type"].ToString())
                {
                    case "getXY":
                        System.Collections.Generic.List<ResultStuff> result = new System.Collections.Generic.List<ResultStuff>();
                        JavaScriptSerializer jsonID = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                        System.Collections.Generic.List<String> assetIDList = jsonID.Deserialize<System.Collections.Generic.List<String>>(Request.Form["firstArray"]);
//more stuff here
                        Response.Write(result);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Response.Write("Request string invalid.");
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Request string missing.");
            }
        }
```

I'd also like to get some results as a response, but I never came that far to peroperly test the code in the aspx. I also tried the traditional flag in the ajaxSetup, but it didn' improve. I did this with simpel data types, which worked fine. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: First of all there is a syntax error: "firstArray": arr, There should be a comma after arr.

Comment: Hi SSA, thanks for your response, that was just a typo when formatting it for the post. I removed some other issues.

Comment: Okay then try with "firstArray": JSON.stringify(arr),
            "secondArray": JSON.stringify(brr),

Comment: Stringifying the arrays didn't work, but applied to the param2 object at least now the parameters seem to be correctly sent. I had to change the contentType for that though: $.ajaxSetup({ contentType: 'application/json' }); - Now I cannot access the parameters in the asp ... Request.Form["type"] gives me null.